# Rails asset pipeline only returns error 404

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

Sorry for the question, as I'm a ruby and rails novice. How do I get the asset pipeline working on rails?

In my development enviroment I have this individual files of javascript and they are loaded normally in **site/app/views/stats/index.html.erb**:

```
<%= javascript_include_tag "/assets/jquery.js" %>
<%= javascript_include_tag "/assets/stats/donut.js" %>
<%= javascript_include_tag "/assets/stats/vbars.js" %>
<%= javascript_include_tag "/assets/stats/progress.js" %>
<%= javascript_include_tag "/assets/stats/gauge.js" %>
<%= javascript_include_tag "/assets/stats/hbars.js" %>
<%= javascript_include_tag "/assets/stats/widget_grid.js" %>
<%= javascript_include_tag "/assets/stats/widget.js" %>
```

In production enviroment it is not working. So I'm trying to get developer enviroment to use asset pipeline. Here's what I got so far:

In **site/config/enviroment/development.rb** I configured

```
config.assets.debug = false
config.assets.compile = false
config.assets.digest = true
```

Then stopped my rails server and ran

```
bundle exec rake assets:precompile
```

and restarted the rails server.

Then in **site/app/views/stats/index.html.erb** I just replaced the javascript includes for

```
<%= javascript_include_tag "stats" %>
```

and created a **site/app/assets/javascripts/stats.js** file that contains

```
//= require stats/donut
//= require stats/vbars
//= require stats/progress
//= require stats/gauge
//= require stats/hbars
//= require stats/widget_grid
//= require stats/widget
```

What am I doing wrong? Any help is appreciated.

---

Update: problem was happening because I forgot to include a third-party library inside stats.js. Originally had this include in **site/app/views/stats/index.html.erb**

```
<%= javascript_include_tag "/assets/third-party/d3.min.js" %>
```

Just had to remove that include and add this one to **stats.js**

```
//= require third-party/d3.min.js
```

Thanks for everybody who helped!

Answer (score 0):

You have to tell Rails to precompile that file. By default it works with `application.js` but if you create a new manifest file, you have to include it. In `config/initializers/assets.rb` or `production.rb` add:

`Rails.application.config.assets.precompile << ['stats.js']`

Hope it helps.

This post is pretty helpful to understand how the asset pipeline works: http://www.reinteractive.net/posts/116-12-tips-for-the-rails-asset-pipeline